# Certificates on Web with Firefox

Tags: firefox, ssl, certificates

How do I update certificates when one has expired?  In Firefox on both 14.4 AND Windows 8.1 I am getting a lot of certificate errors-  either expired or do not recognize the name on certificate.  By far this happens on 14.4 much more.  Although I can sometimes add them to exceptions this is not always true (and I would rather it worked properly anyway).  I know from reading some other responses here that Firefox segregates certificates by user, but I am the only user on this machine.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

To update all certificates do:

```
    sudo update-ca-certificates -f
```